# Problem during installation on SSD

Tags: installation, windows-8, ssd

My system run Windows 8 updated to 8.1.
Because of incompatibility from windows 8.1 with my hardware (old MB Asus P5BSE with Core2 Quad Q6600, but the disk is a SSD Samsung 830 Series), I want to delete all and install Ubuntu.

When I try to install v12.04.3, I read this error (in Italian): `tentativo di montare un file system di tipo ext4 in SCSI(0,0,0) ... non riuscito`.

How to solve??

Comment: Can you try booting into a live instance (choose 'Try Ubuntu' instead of install at the first screen) and see if you can mount & format the SSD that way?

Comment: I have used live cd (first 'try ubuntu', second GParted on Hiren's boot cd), I can manage partition.
But when I try to install, same error.

Comment: If I retry to install from inside live cd, same error. In the black window (log) appear text like 'ubuntu kernel (...) end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 117720064'

Comment: Another attempt using v.13.10. In this case, the error is 'il tentativo di montare un file system di tipo ext4 in LVM VG ubuntu-vg,LV root su / non riuscito'. It's possible that previous windows 8.1 made something on the SSD and now it's impossible to use the disk with ubuntu?

Comment: You should add your last comment as an answer!

Comment: Solved. 

1) Shutdown pc  
2) Remove SSD and connect them to another PC via usb   
3) Format SSD using XP (I choose NTFS, complete)

4) Return to original hardware configuration  
5) Installation of ubuntu 13.10  
6) NOW IT WORKS!


For me, it's a mistery
(I tried to answer but I cannot post until 8 hours from first post. I leave comment)

Answer (score 2):

The installer was trying to write to the drive treating it as a ext4 partition, however since Windows had been installed on it it may not have been properly formatted as ext4.

Make sure when installing you reformat the entire drive using the default partitioning options (unless you have a specific need to change the options).

Answer (score 0):

I move the comment in answer:

Solved. 
1) Shutdown pc 
2) Remove SSD and connect them to another PC via usb 
3) Format SSD using XP (I choose NTFS, complete) 
4) Return to original hardware configuration 
5) Installation of ubuntu 13.10 
6) NOW IT WORKS!

For me, it's a mistery